Docker php - symfony container can't publish to mercure container
I've got a compose.yaml file that seems to be ok but when i send an update, i get this error: Failed to connect to mercure.probex.localhost port 443 after 0 ms: Couldn't connect to server for "https://mercure.probex.localhost/.well-known/mercure".
Here is my compose.yaml file
version: "3"

services:
  database:
    platform: linux/amd64
    image: icr.io/informix/informix-developer-database:latest
    privileged: true
    ports:
      - "9089:9088"
    environment:
      LICENSE: "accept"
      DB_LOCALE: "en_US.819"
      CLIENT_LOCALE: "en_US.utf8"
      DBDATE: "DMY4."
      DBMONEY: "F,"
      DBFORMAT: "F:,:.:"
      INIT_FILE: "sql/init.sql"
    volumes:
      - db_data:/opt/ibm/data
      - ./docker/informix/export:/opt/ibm/informix/export
      - ./docker/informix/sql:/opt/ibm/config/sql
      - ./docker/informix/script:/home/informix/script
    networks:
      - probex_app

  php:
    platform: linux/amd64
    build:
      context: ./docker/php
      args:
        GITLAB_TOKEN: ${GITLAB_TOKEN}
    depends_on:
      - database
    environment:
      MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN: redis://redis:6379/messages
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/symfony:cached
      - ./docker/php/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-config.ini
      - ./docker/php/www.conf:/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
      - symfony_app_var:/var/www/symfony/var
    networks:
      - web
      - probex_app

  nginx:
    build:
      context: ./docker/nginx
    depends_on:
      - php
    environment:
      NGINX_BACKEND_DOMAIN: ${CURRENT_DOMAIN}
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/symfony:cached
      - symfony_app_var:/var/www/symfony/var
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.docker.network=web
      - traefik.http.routers.probex-api.rule=Host(`api.probex.localhost`)
      - traefik.http.routers.probex-api.tls=true
    networks:
      - web
      - probex_app

  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    networks:
      - probex_app

  mercure:
    image: dunglas/mercure
    environment:
      SERVER_NAME: ':80'
      MERCURE_PUBLISHER_JWT_KEY: '!ChangeMe!'
      MERCURE_SUBSCRIBER_JWT_KEY: '!ChangeMe!'
      ALLOW_ANONYMOUS: 1
      CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS: "*"
      PUBLISH_ALLOWED_ORIGINS: "*"
      DEMO: 1
    command: /usr/bin/caddy run --config /etc/caddy/dev.Caddyfile
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.docker.network=web
      - traefik.http.routers.probex-mercure.rule=Host(`mercure.probex.localhost`)
      - traefik.http.routers.probex-mercure.tls=true
    volumes:
      - mercure_data:/data
      - mercure_config:/config
    networks:
      - web
      - probex_app

volumes:
  db_data:
  symfony_app_var:
  mercure_data:
  mercure_config:

networks:
  probex_app:
  web:
    external: true


In the browser i can see the mercure UI page so the traefik part is ok, and i think i can subscribe to topics from the browser but impossible to publish to mercure from the php container, i've tried a lot of different configurations but with the same impossibility.
If anyone has an idea or a working configuration, it would be appreciated
